# create script to analyze log file

Tags: python, bash, parsing, logging, socket.io

I'm trying to analyze a log file created by socketio like that :

```
2020-06-12 14:40 +02:00: * 2020-06-12T12:40:44.728Z +   connect viewer: xxxxxx room: e4c60 viewers actuel [ e4c60: 370, '44c0d': 1 ] socket.id: /viewers#qnm6nJtDSSVA2N-oAAO0
...
2020-06-12 15:51 +02:00: * 2020-06-12T13:51:39.889Z - disconnect viewer: xxxxxx room: e4c60 viewers actuel [ e4c60: 26, e3fa1: 3, '44c0d': 1 ] socket.id: /viewers#qnm6nJtDSSVA2N-oAAO0
...
2020-06-12 15:51 +02:00: * 2020-06-12T13:51:46.978Z +   connect viewer: vvvvvvv room: e4c60 viewers actuel [ e4c60: 27, e3fa1: 3, '44c0d': 1 ] socket.id: /viewers#w03eaaUVq6mL2SzPAAS1
...
2020-06-12 15:58 +02:00: * 2020-06-12T13:58:01.377Z - disconnect viewer: vvvvvvv room: e4c60 viewers actuel [ e4c60: 23, e3fa1: 3, '44c0d': 1 ] socket.id: /viewers#w03eaaUVq6mL2SzPAAS1
```

what I want is to get sockets uptime and get in the end an average.

So to get that, I need to catch : date + "socket.id" value then the disconnect from the same socket.id with the date... and in the end to make the difference between the 2 dates in seconds ; room name is also important because I need results per room in the end

I need to do that for each entry in log file and finally take all "differences" to get an average in seconds

If you have an idea how to do that easily in any language (bash, python...)
Thanks

Comment: You have forgotten to add your code or what you have tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: well... almost nothing because in trying with few sed/awk/grep it doesn't solve all
biggest problem is to catch info already parsed then do next entry

Comment: consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question; in particular, show sample input, what code you've tried, the incorrect output (from your code), and the desired (correct) ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This python code should work.

```
from datetime import datetime

status_dict = {}
diff_list = []

with open('test_data.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        date = datetime.strptime(line.split(' ')[4], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        socket_id = line.split('#')[1].strip()
        if 'connect' in line:
            status = 'connect'
        else:
            status = 'disconnect'
        if socket_id in status_dict:
            diff = (date - status_dict[socket_id]['date']).total_seconds()
            diff_list.append(diff)
            print(f'Socket ID: {socket_id} closed after {diff} seconds.')
        else:
            status_dict[socket_id] = {'date':date, 'status':status}

print(f'Average connected time: {sum(diff_list)/len(diff_list)} seconds.')
```

Output looks like this for the data you provided:

```
Socket ID: qnm6nJtDSSVA2N-oAAO0 closed after 4255.161 seconds.
Socket ID: w03eaaUVq6mL2SzPAAS1 closed after 374.399 seconds.
Average connected time: 2314.78 seconds.
```

I'm sure there are many ways to do it better, but this should work for you if the data is consistent with the samples you posted.

Comment: thanks FranksNBeans
I need to adapt it again but it's great, it's close to what I need
thanks again